# Performance on VMWare Workstation or Virtual Machines generally

Tags: virtualization, vmware, vmware-workstation

How well would my VMWare perform in terms of speed and smooth experience if I was running apps like Android Studio or other CPU-intensive apps?

I plan on using Ubuntu distro for the VM ware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance of VMware (or other Virtualizing application) depends on the capability of the host machine.

A host machine with 16 GB of memory, a fast SSD drive, and an i7 CPU will perform very well - host and virtual machine. I have such a laptop and work in side VMware machines frequently with no performance drop or lag.

You can assign resources to a virtual machine (number of CPUs and memory) and it will function pretty much like a physical machine.

A high end i5 CPU works as does a fast 7200-rpm hard drive. It will take longer for machines to start, but the environment is workable.

Slow hard drive, low end CPU and little memory drive down the performance of a Virtual Machine.

Comment: So you mean essentially, if I have a 16gb ram and I allocate 12gb for the VM, I'd have exact processing power of my PC if it were a regular 12gb windows?

Comment: I normally allocate 2 to 4 GB for a machine and that works well for my machines. If you need it, you can allocate more. This is a dynamic setting that you can change to suit your needs.